# Dell Inspiron with Windows 10 does not connect to WiFi but other devices will

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10

I have a Dell Inspiron Laptop, Windows 10 and it won't connect to the Wi-Fi in my home any more. All other devices (Phones, Blu-ray, Other Laptops) connect without issue. It was connected and working for months, but it just stopped last week for no apparent reason. It is showing the wireless networks but it won't connect to mine (others are blocked going to try a public one today). I have disabled and re-enabled the Network adapter, uninstalled and re-installed it and it still gives me the "Cannot Connect to Network." Can someone help me?

Comment: Have you tried rebooting the machine?  Not shutting it down and powering up later, an actual reboot...

Comment: Have you tried deleting the saved WiFi network profile and then reconnecting to it?

Comment: Yes to deleting and reconnecting. And by reboot, do you mean a factory reset or something along those lines?

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem after I upgraded my wireless network.  The answer turned out to be to update the wireless card driver in my PC.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the first dell related search result. 
http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/SLN297743

If the obvious isn't the answer, then read on.

First, try connecting to another wifi signal... I doubt this is the issue, but its worth a shot. If you need a quick signal to grab onto turn on your phones hotspot.

If you can connect, then it probably means your router is being a stubborn old fool and not sending out IP addresses as it should. What I would recommend is turn off everything connected to the router, both wired and wirelessly and then power down the router, and restart. Then start turning everything else back on.

Try going into cmd and typing ipconfig, what do you see there? Since your connecting through a router it should start with 192.bleh but I have a feeling it wont.

Question, did you JUST install windows 10 and now the wifi isn't working? Sorry, but you never really mentioned that in your initial post.

Comment: No, the laptop has had Windows 10 the entire time. The router is pushing the IP address out just fine, as my daughter's blu-ray player, my phone, and her laptop all connect effortlessly to the signal. I had been connected as of last week, and it just stopped working. It sees all the networks, but I can't connect to mine anymore. I will try connecting to another signal. I have already tried powering down everything connected but I will try again.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on my Dell and couldn't find a good answer for my problem. I had to right click on my start menu and go to network adapters I believe (I'm not near my computer). I then had to click on my Dell wireless card where it popped up with a screen to let me diagnose my problem. It came up with the dhcp was not enable. I was able to get it enabled without even being connected to the internet. The problem was fixed immediately without having to reboot